# Google Maps displaying custom paths

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, gdirections

I'm trying to customize the icons drawn by the GDirections object. I've got a list of lat long coordinates which I use to construct a path. However, I can't find any way of customizing (or even turning off) the markers that are automatically placed by the API.

```
var map;
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
.... //get the path coordinates
var route = new GDirections(map);
route.load(path_coordinates);
```

Calling `route.getPolyline().hide()` hides the path but not the markers. Calling `route.getMarker(1).isHidden()` returns true and obviously hiding it doesn't change anything. 
Is this functionality not supported by the api?
I'm using map api 2.81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var map;
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
.... //get the path coordinates
var route = new GDirections(map);
route.load(path_coordinates);
GEvent.addListener(route , "addoverlay", hideDirMarkers); 
function hideDirMarkers(){ 
        var numMarkers = route.getNumGeocodes() 
        for (var i = 0; i < numMarkers; i++) { 
                var marker = route.getMarker(i); 
                if (marker != null) 
                        marker.hide(); 
                else 
                        alert("Marker is null"); 
        } 
}
```